# Using Ajax to auto-refresh page that contains php generated image causes errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In the code below, somepage.php is image.  If I use , the generated image shows fine.  However, when using Ajax to refresh the div that contains somepage.php, I get garbled text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#graph").load("someimage.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#graph").load('someimage.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph-title">
    <h1>Current Online Users by Country</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. </p>
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in.</p> 
</div>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What garbled text do you get?

Comment: @dbh I get �PNGIHDR�?z�jIDATx� followed by another 30 lines of similar characters.

Comment: @user2755910, that looks like the beginning of a png file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your script is outputting an image stream when a `randval` is used and an html `img` tag otherwise.

You probably want your javascript to only change the source attribute of an image as a script cannot output html and an image at the same time (it actually could, but then you'd have to put the source base64 encoded in the source attribute...).

Posting your `someimage.php` script could confirm that.

Comment: @user2755910 To avoid that, you can generate an image in javascript, add an `onLoad` function and only then set the source. Then you can switch the image when the new one is completely loaded, see for example http://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event or search here on SO.